# Round-Robin Scheduling with Arrival Times

Tags: scheduled-tasks, scheduling, round-robin

So in class, my professor was going over round robin scheduling. Consider this situation:

```
Job       |    Arrival       |      Burst
A         |       0          |        3
B         |       1          |        5
C         |       3          |        4
```

My professor wrote down the results as follows:

```
Time
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
A A B A B B C C B C  B  C
```

At times `0-1`, `A` has being processed for one burst. At time `1-2`, `A` is being processed for another burst. At time `2-3` `B` is being processed for a burst, and so on and so forth.

What I'm confused about is at times `6-8`. `B` is processed again from time `5-6`. Then `C` from time `6-7`, and `C` again from time `7-8`. Shouldn't it instead be this:

```
Time
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12
A A B A B C B C B C  B  C
```

Comment: It does look like it should be as you say, but how about asking your professor? It might just have been a mistake on his/her part.

Answer (score 0):

At first each and every round robin question is based on quantum.(ex-quantum = 4). It means each and every process will take same quantum time for execution.
for your example if quantum=2.
then
it seems like

```
A        B      C       A     B       C          B

0  -  2  - A

2  -  4  - B

4  - 6   - C

6  - 7   - A

7  - 9   - B

9  - 11  - c   

11 -12   - B
```

Waiting time of process
Waiting time = (starting time of final execution  – previous executed cycle – arrival time)

```
A –  (6-2-0)=4


B – (11-(2+2)-1)=6

C – (9-2)-3=4

Average waiting time = (4+6+4)/3 = 14/3 = 4.66
```

Comment: Sorry i was not allowed to post an image so i didn't elaborate very well.

Comment: Average waiting time = (4+6+4)/3 = 14/3 = 4.66

Answer (score 0):

The other answers I believe are incorrect. After process A ends at time 2, B will be added to the queue since it has arrived and then A will be added back to the queue since it has not finished execution and C is not available yet. Job C will be added to the queue at time 4 after B has utilized it's first quantum. The correct order should be as follows:

```
A: 2
B: 2
A: 1
C: 2
B: 2
C: 2
B: 1
Average waiting time: 4.0
```